# placing 3 divs next to each other in a div on undefined size

Tags: html, css

i have a header, which takes the whole width of the screen. in my header i want to place 3 divs, which should be aligned next to each other. the div's on the side being fixed-width, and the middle should take the other space available. so i don't know the width of the header, and i don't know the width of the middle container.

right now i have this code:
html:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="menu-container">
    menu goes here
  </div>
  <div id="logo-container">
    logo goes here
  </div>
  <div id="music-player-container">
    music player comes here
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#header {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#menu-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
}

#logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

#music-player-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
}
```

which should be working according to other problems with the float.... it doesn't

Comment: Is it possible to take a look at your markup

Comment: sorry, first post, didn't get the code formatting well.. here it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use floated divs with negative margins:

http://jsfiddle.net/cy5E7/1/

**In your case:**

http://jsfiddle.net/AjVHy/

Negative margins are better then just left/right float fixed divs. We don't get messed layout if user have very small window. Look at this **bad** example (resize browser window to small width): http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/qZLHb/1/ (thanks to @SVS). In normal float layout, all floated divs are on place only if parent container is wide enough.

Another disadvantage of standard float layout is when we want column layout but we don't know height of middle content, look like it can look

- [float layout, dynamic content height](http://jsfiddle.net/cy5E7/4/)
- [negative margins layout, dynamic content height](http://jsfiddle.net/cy5E7/3/)

Comment: +1 good one i like the trick. It will be good if you explain what negative margins are actually doing. As i always do this in a wrong way like here http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/qZLHb/1/

Comment: But in this case, the fixed-width div widths are known so the user would obviously make sure the parent div wider then their combined width.

Comment: @user1410620 If the answer was helpful - please mark it as accepted (tickmark below vote count). This will mark the question as closed +small rep. bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of your second and third divs then use this CSS.

```
#menu-container, #music-player-container {
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
}
#music-player-container {
    float:right;
}
#logo-container {
    margin:0 400px;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mf6qr/)

Comment: You also might want to change all those ID's to classes unless you need them as ID's for scripting purposes. Otherwise, you can end up with a messy style sheet with too much specificity.

Comment: What is the problem? This doesn't use negative margins.

Comment: Forgot to tell you to switch your second and third div in the html. Here is fiddle showing that this works.http://jsfiddle.net/mf6qr/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you are planning to code up, but in my perspective, I see it like this: "You want to have 3 columns, column 1 being of a fixed with, column 2 a fluid width and column 3 yet again of fixed width."

What I fail to understand here is that, in the case of a really small width monitor (like a 1024x768 resolution, for instance), having a 400px column on both sides would leave you with just 224px of logo space. It would look un-natural.

Anyways, if you would still like to continue, I suggest you enclose all the three divs [`menu-container, logo-container & music-player-container`] inside another element called header (If you're using HTML5) or another div with any name you like (If you're using <= HTML 4.01) and then fix it's width to 100%; and a fixed height of 200px;.

Then let the menu-container, `float: left;` and the music-player-container `float: right;`. This will give space to the logo-container. Let the logo-container have a `width: auto;`. Having done this will give you a basic semi-fluid header layout, if I'm right.

Cheers, hope your question gets solved quick :)

Comment: yeah, maybe i should change the sizes, but that doesn't matter for now... the problem i have with this approach is that the third collumn (#music-player-container) ends up below the other two containers. in the right horizontal position, but below the header instead of inside the header.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, and I am sorry to say that I have yet to find a solution for this issue without using some ugly form of JavaScript/jQuery.

Essentially, the problem is that CSS does not have any properties (not even when fiddling with display properties) that will allow you to have two elements, one with fixed width and the other taking up the remainder of the space in the div. There are some options with float that can allow you to very closely simulate this, but I can tell you that they are unlikely to give you what you really want.

There is a resource out there, a project called Bootstrap, that you can install like any other jQuery plugin (or you can actually use it like a "CSS" plugin - you'll see what I mean - if you don't want the JavaScript), that will enable you to do what you want.

Here is the link: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html

I strongly recommend that you review the documentation first to make sure you are aware of any caveats/limitations.

Good Luck!

EDIT: I like rogal's answer, but before using it you should bear in mind that doing so removes your ability to add a left border and makes it very difficult to apply background images to the div with the negative margin.

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
#header {
    display: table;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
#header > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: inherit;
}
#menu-container, #music-player-container {
    width: 400px;
}
#logo-container {
    background-image: url('../images/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

HTH

Comment: But table-cell isn't supported in IE is it?

Comment: I have tested in IE 8 and it works fine. ATM I don't have access to an earlier version.

Comment: True but I don't think IE7 usage is low enough to warrant abandoning it's support - as much as I hate having to cater to IE. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course use a table..
-*hides*-

Something like this inside the header div:

```
<table width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            menu
        </td>
        <td>
            logo
        </td>
        <td width=400>
            music
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(too lazy for CSS atm)

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a very good way to do this. Not an ideal solution, but you could turn this into a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can just set the dimensions of the div and the td that contains it to be the same.

Comment: Do you have any css to it also?

Comment: In fact the top voted answer has the div-solution, so there is no need to convert divs into tables.